# Access object value javascript

Tags: javascript

I logged the following:

```
console.log(io.nsps['/'].adapter.rooms[socket.room]);
```

and it returned the following:

```
Room { sockets: { '/#O6L2als5FU-VfHSoAAAA': true }, length: 1 }
```

How might I edit `console.log` so that it returns the `length` value? I tried `.length`, `.sockets.length`, I also added `[1]` to the end. These were all unsuccessful.

Answer (score 2):

Since .length is reserved, it returned "Cannot read property 'length' of undefined". Using ["length"] fixed the issue.

Comment: "Since .length is reserved" --- WAT

Comment: I agree David, but it's not mine to change. And to zerkms, I hope that I did not misuse the term 'reserved'.

Comment: @manbearpig1 uhm, there is nothing special about `.length`. You can freely assign a property with that name to your object. "Cannot read property 'length' of undefined" error message is about WHERE you read from not WHAT you read.

Comment: length is the key which has a value of 1 in this case, while .length is a method that evaluates the length of something.

Comment: `.length` and `['length']` are guaranteed by the standard to be evaluated in the same way. If you're using a JS engine that complies with the standard - there is no way to see any difference between how those are interpreted.

Comment: Yes they will return the value from the key called 'length' in the same way, but .length is a reserved method and this method takes priority over returning key values. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_length_string.asp

Comment: `.length` is not a method, it's a property. And it's not "reserved".

Comment: Feel free to test this exact case for yourself and see what the result is.

Comment: It does not. You did not test it.

Comment: Well, whatever. Have fun.

Comment: I have to insist that you try the exact test case that I described. Yours is not analogous.

Comment: Yeah I've been watching this unfold and have to throw in the mix that zerkms is exactly right. We can't replicate exactly because you didn't include the actual data in your question.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/u2hp8vb4/1/ --- it works without problems with the expression you have.

Comment: `obj.length` and `obj["length"]` are syntactically identical. *length* is not an [*ECMAScript reserved word*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-reserved-words).

Answer (score 1):

`console.log(io.nsps['/'].adapter.rooms[socket.room].length);` should work